# URL Rewriting with "!" (exclamation mark)

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am stuck with this challenge, and I really hope that someone can help me out.

I am currently working on an API, and a friendly URL is needed to call on the API.

A VOLKSWAGEN manufacture has released a car called UP!

If you notice there is an exclamation on the brand type. This has created an issue with the .htaccess because it lands to 404 page.

Sample URL:
http://mysite.com/cars/new/VOLKSWAGEN/UP!

Has anyone ever encountered this issue, and solved it?

This is my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]    
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)!$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will remove trailing `!` from all URIs.

Comment: How can we do dame thing if it comes like this. 
 mysite.com/cars/new/VOLKSWAGEN/!UP

Comment: mysite.com/cars/new/VOLKSWAGEN/!UP

Comment: @Mahesh: That appears to be a different problem. I suggest you post a new question with clarification so that I can answer it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). I'm not quite sure what you mean by "friendly", but you simply can't have an exclamation-point character in an HTTP URL. Most browsers these days are translating encoded characters into their equivalents on the address bar, though.